# how to use cmake to process .c files and .l files

Tags: cmake, flex-lexer

I created a `calc.l` file（which will be processed by flex for generate a `calc.c` file），and this `calc.l` file contains a header file `token.h`. Also I created a `test.c` file (to use the `calc.c` process it). But I don't know how to write a `CMakeLists.txt` to achieve this effect.

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(calc) 

find_package(FLEX REQUIRED)
FLEX_TARGET(calc_lexer calc.l ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/calc.c)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# main
set (MAIN_SRC ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/calc_lex.c)
add_executable(calc ${MAIN_SRC})
```

Comment: If I don't use cmake，the commands will be：
flex calc.l    (which will generate a lex.yy.c file)
gcc -o calc lex.yy.c
./calc < test.c > output.txt

Comment: You show your `CMakeLists.txt`, but whether it works? If it causes the error, then add the **error message** to the question post. BTW, you specified output file for `FLEX_TARGET` as `calc.c`, but for compilation you specified a **different file**, `calc_lex.c`.

Comment: There is no error , I just don't know how it should be structured for a project like this，What I have done so far is to convert this calc.l file into a calc.c file through flex and run it, but I still don't know how to use this generated calc.c file to process the test.c file. Maybe my expression Not very clear, sorry

Comment: "I still don't know how to use this generated calc.c file to process the test.c file" - You pass that generated `calc.c` to `add_executable`, which will create the program to run. Then you run that program. What is unclear in that process? It exactly corresponds to your command-line usage.